# lucene / hibernate search - Cannot search by fields in subclass in collection

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I have:
A `Request` entity has a collection of `Stage`s and each stage has a collection of `StageItem`s. Stage items can be of several types and I use for them in JPA/Hibernate `SINGLE_TABLE` as inheritance strategy with a discriminator column.

I need my lucene query to return requests that have a particular detail in a stage item of type A (field `aDetail` in class `StageItemA`). I cannot get hibernate search to see the field `aDetail` in the subclass `StageItemA`.

So this lucene query does not work (returns 0 results):

```
stages.stageItems.aDetail:blah
```

But searching based on fields in `StageItem` works:

```
stages.stageItems.comment:yuppie
```

Using Luke, I can the fields from `StageItem`, like `stages.stageItems.comment`, but no field from `StageItemA`, like `stages.stageItems.aDetail`.

Entity definitions:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUEST")
@Indexed(index = "RequestIndex")
class Request implements Serializable {
    //...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "type", length = 50, nullable = false)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "REQUEST_STAGE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STAGE_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Map<String, Stage> stages = new HashMap<>();
    //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "STAGE")
public class Stage implements Serializable {
    //...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = StageItem.class, cascade = {
            CascadeType.ALL,
    }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "STAGE_TO_STAGE_ITEM",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STAGE_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STAGE_ITEM_ID")
    )
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Set<StageItem> stageItems = new HashSet<>();
    //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "STAGE_ITEM")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class StageItem implements Serializable {
    //...
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    @Field
    protected String type;

    @Column(name="COMMENT")
    @Field
    protected String comment;
    //...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "A")
public class StageItemA extends StageItem {
    //...
    @Column(name="A_DETAIL")
    @Field
    private String aDetail;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@IndexedEmbedded` only considers the *declared* type of your property, not the *runtime* type. So with you current mapping, `@IndexedEmbedded` will only index fields declared in class `StageItem`, not those declared in `StageItemA`.

There are plans to change that and take into account runtime polymorphism, but we're not quite there yet: it's not as obvious as it seems because of corner cases where we'd need to detect conflicts in the index schema between multiple subclasses. See [HSEARCH-438](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-438) to track progress and find more information.

In the meantime, the easiest way out would be for you to declare a method and field in returning null in `StageItem`, and to override it in `StageItemA` to return the correct value.

Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STAGE_ITEM")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class StageItem implements Serializable {
    //...
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    @Field
    protected String type;

    @Column(name="COMMENT")
    @Field
    protected String comment;
    //...

    @Field(name = "aDetail")
    @javax.persistence.Transient
    protected String getADetailForHibernateSearch() {
        return null;
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "A")
public class StageItemA extends StageItem {
    //...
    @Column(name="A_DETAIL")
    private String aDetail;
    //...

    @Override
    protected String getADetailForHibernateSearch() {
        return aDetail;
    }
}
```

The main drawback is that indexing a transient method has negative impact on performance: in short, since Hibernate Search doesn't know where the data comes from, it will consider that *any* change to *any* property of a StageItem requires reindexing, whereas previously it would only have triggered reindexing when a relevant property was modified. You can try it though, the performance hit may not be that bad in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try it, but I have a question about "reindexing" when any property of `StageItem` changes: what exactly is reindexed: the whole of `RequestIndex` of just a tinny part of the index (the part corresponding to the changed StageItem), or more of the index, like all the parts corresponding to all requests that are using that stage item or what? Thank you.

Comment: When a StageItem changes, all the requests that include it will be (completely) reindexed. But you need to mark the association from StageItem to Request with `@ContainedIn` for that to work. See [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-associated) No, there is not support for partial reindexing yet.

Comment: I understand and can implement the workaround you describe.  However, it's unsatisfying in that it involves leaking subclass details into the parent class. (If I can call `getADetailForHibernateSearch()` from `StageItem` and from `StageItemA`, why use a class hierarchy at all?)  Hibernate handles the class hierarchy elegantly, by comparison.  Are there features in Hibernate Search 6 that would change your answer to this question?  Would it be possible or reasonable to use a custom bridge on StageItem in this case?

Comment: You're leaking subclass details into the parent class, but that's what you want: you're asking to be able to search for `StageItemA` content even though `Stage` only guarantees it exposes a `StageItem`. In Hibernate ORM, you would put a [`treat` statement](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-downcast-entities-jpql-queries/) in your query. No, Hibernate Search 6 still doesn't support runtime polymorphism. Yes, you could use a custom bridge, but then I'd recommend Hibernate Search 6 as [bridge support was significantly improved](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/#bridge-2.0).